# Como puedo ejecutar docker sin sudo en ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, docker

```
> docker ps
    Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.24/containers/json: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied
```

..

```
69904 -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 71578680 jun  2 13:54 /usr/bin/docker
```

Quiero ejecutar **docker** sin la necesidad de usar sudo. No se que deberia de cambiar exactamente.

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/ > Si no desea correr el comando docker con `sudo`, cree un grupo Unix llamado `docker` y agréguele usuarios (el tuyo en este caso). Cuando se inicia el daemon de Docker, crea un socket Unix al que pueden acceder los miembros del grupo de `docker`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes que añadir tu usuario al grupo de usuarios "docker", desde tu usuario ejecuta:

```
sudo usermod -aG docker $USER
```

Tienes que cerrar tu sesión de usuario y volverla abrir para que se aplique el cambio.

Saludos

Comment: Es necesario aclarar las cuestiones de seguridad que implica hacer esto, [aqui](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/#docker-daemon-attack-surface) la documentación de docker al respecto.